# Cannot resolve symbol "add" while adding class object to an ArrayList

Tags: java

I am working on a class for an Address Book Application on Java called "AddressBook.java", which I have written the following code:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class AddressBook {
    ArrayList<AddressEntry> addressEntryList = new ArrayList<AddressEntry>();
    AddressEntry test = new AddressEntry("john", "doe", "yes", "no", "maybe", 1, "I guess", "ok");
    
    addressEntryList.add(test);
}
```

Since I was just testing the test object, I had to give random values for the variables from my AddressEntry class and it seemed to work well. However, when I ran it in IntelliJ, I received the error

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'add'
```

This made the adding method not working.

Comment: See Java Tutorials by Oracle, showing a `main` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html

Answer (score 4):

**You need to put it inside the main method.**

Like this:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class AddressBook {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<AddressEntry> addressEntryList = new ArrayList<AddressEntry>();
        AddressEntry test = new AddressEntry("john", "doe", "yes", "no", "maybe", 1, "I guess", "ok");
        addressEntryList.add(test);
    }
}
```

**Java cannot resolve method calls if the method call does not call from any method.**

Comment: Cole - please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258187

Comment: First off, the original post contained some terminology that was of a sexual nature. Second, the whole "Hope that helps" is something the community has decided is unnecessary. Do not revert this post again.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use your `ArrayList` object methods (for example `.add`, `.remove` etc) inside other methods, this can also be the `main` method (obviously)